# Drupal 7 db_query using CAST

Tags: 7, database

Does Drupal 7's DB API support SQL's CAST function? I have a varchar with numbers in it that I'm trying to convert to integers for proper sorting. Here's my statement:

```
$images = db_query('SELECT filename, caption FROM {iha_captions}
WHERE uid = :uid ORDER BY CAST(weight AS INT) ASC', array(':uid' => $userid));
```

And here is the error I get:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INT) ASC' at line 1: SELECT filename, caption FROM {iha_captions} WHERE uid = :uid ORDER BY CAST(weight AS INT) ASC; Array ( [:uid] => 2814 ) in iha_search_profile()

It then causes a cascade of SQL failures in Drupal's session and cache queries. Is `CAST` supported, or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a Drupal error; it comes from the MySQL engine about [CAST using](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html):

> The type can be one of the following values:
>       BINARY[(N)]
>       CHAR[(N)]
>       DATE
>       DATETIME
>       DECIMAL[(M[,D])]
>       SIGNED [INTEGER]
>       TIME
>       UNSIGNED [INTEGER]

You cannot use `INT`; it should be `SIGNED`, `UNSIGNED` or `DECIMAL`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a Drupal error it's a MySQL error. [`CAST()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html) won't accept `INT` as a valid type but does give you a choice between `SIGNED` and `UNSIGNED` to cast to an integer type.

The following query runs fine for me in Drupal:

```
SELECT * FROM node ORDER BY CAST(nid AS UNSIGNED)
```